# User a {id} inside a route on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I need to put a id number in the middle of an URL to get this:

```
http://myapp.com/something/29/edit
```

Now, I have this:

```
'user_link' => ['here.i.need.to.put.my.route.with.the.number]
```

My number comes from `$event->data->id`, is there a way to "concatenate" a number in the middle of a route? Something like

```
'user_link' => ['something.{id}.edit]
'user_link' => ['something.'.$event->data->id .'.edit] <-- I I do that Laravel shows an error: Route [something.{107}.edit] not defined
```

The route in question is:

```
Route::get('something/{id}/edit/', 'MyController@edit')->name('something.edit');
```

It's possible to put a {id} in the `name` of the route?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `route()` helper:

```
route('something.edit', ['id' => $event->data->id])
```

Comment: I need to put the id in the middle of the route, at the end there no problem. If I did that I'll get: `Route [http://myapp.com/something/edit?id=109] not defined`. My route needs to be like this `http://myapp.com/something/109/edit`

Comment: `route()` will add ID instead of `{id}` placeholder, not just add it to the end of the URI.

Comment: With `'{id}'=> $event->data->id])` worked... I think I have a mistake. Thanks mate, this is what I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put an `id` in a route name. It's bad practice in my opinion. 
I would suggest that you use route resource.

```
php artisan make:resource MyController -m Something
```

This way, you can restful routes:

```
my/index
my/create
my/store
my/{something}/edit
my/{something}/update
my/{something}/show
my/{something}/destroy
```

By the above pattern, your edit route will be `/my/10/edit`, and you data will be automatically fetched.

This way you can use policies to determine that item currently being updated belongs to the logged in user.